Colouring rows breaks after 23 lines
I have the below code which is supposed colour the rows based on the colour of the row above it. However, when I run the code, the result is as expected for around 15 lines and then it stops working and starts to colour in the rows with just text in them.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Counter, No_Of_Rows, Last_Delete, No_Of_Cols As Long
Dim Col_Letter, Col_Range As String

No_Of_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
No_Of_Cols = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Counter = 7
Last_Delete = 1
Col_Letter = Chr(No_Of_Cols + 64)
Col_Range = "A1" & ":" & Col_Letter & "1"

Do While Counter <= No_Of_Rows
    If Cells(Counter, 1) = "Delete" Then
        Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 51, 0)
        Last_Delete = Last_Delete + 1
    ElseIf Cells(Counter, 1) = " " Or IsEmpty(Cells(Counter, 1)) Or Cells(Counter, 1) = "" Then
        Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = Rows(Counter - 1).Cells(1, Counter - 1).Interior.Color
    Else
        If Last_Delete = 1 Then
            If Rows(Counter - 1).Cells(1, Counter - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
            Else
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        Else
            If Rows(Counter - Last_Delete).Cells(1, Counter - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
                Last_Delete = 1
            Else
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Last_Delete = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Counter = Counter + 1
    
    Loop

End Sub



I am not sure why this happens, I have changed the values around and the error still occurs after a few iterations.

Don't you need instead Rows(Counter - 1).Cells(1, Counter - 1) this: Cells(Counter-1,1) and instead Rows(Counter - Last_Delete).Cells(1, Counter - 1) this: Cells(Counter-Last_Delete,1)?

I'm having a hard time figuring out your colouring logic.  Could you break it down for me?

Is there a reason you don't use conditional formatting for this? I believe =ISODD(COUNTA($A$7:$A7)) will achieve the colouring you want

@TinMan HI, so we have numbers in the A column which relate to houses on a site. Then points 1-2 in row B relate to that first number. So usually a plot will have 4 points however, this can change so I cant make it change every 4 rows.
We want to alternate between the 2 colours for visibility sake. And then if we need to delete a plot, the delete section was supposed to see that they would be deleted and colour the cells accordingly, then resume the colouring from the set before the deleted.

It looks like CDP1802 nailed the code.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, NoOfColumns As Long
    Dim dColor As Long, dLastColor As Long, r As Long
    Dim COLOR1 As Long, COLOR2 As Long, COLOR3 As Long
    
    COLOR1 = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    COLOR2 = RGB(221, 217, 196)
    COLOR3 = RGB(153, 51, 0) ' delete
    dLastColor = COLOR1
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        NoOfColumns = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For r = 7 To LastRow
        
            If .Cells(r, 1) = "Delete" Then
                dColor = COLOR3
            ElseIf IsEmpty(.Cells(r, 1)) Or Len(Trim(.Cells(r, 1))) = 0 Then
                ' no change
                dColor = dLastColor
            Else
                ' toggle color
                If dLastColor = COLOR1 Then
                    dColor = COLOR2
                Else
                    dColor = COLOR1
                End If
                dLastColor = dColor
            End If
            
            ' color row
            .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, NoOfColumns).Interior.Color = dColor
        
        Next
    End With

End Sub


I tried to do something similar but it seems to me that the Deleted row color alternates based on the previous Deleted row color.  If Rows(Counter - Last_Delete).Cells(1, Counter - 1) throw me off.

@TinMan I understood that to just ignore deleted lines by increasing the offset back to the line before the deleted ones with the Last_Delete = Last_Delete + 1

I think that you are correct.  Thanks!
